# How to set date format on Delphi Rio - Undeclared identifier: 'shortdateformat'

Tags: delphi

I'm coming from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 10.3.3 .

In D2007 i used the commands below to make sure the date would be handled by the app with the desired format :

```
shortdateformat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
dateseparator := '/';
```

Now the same commands would fail on D10.3.3 with the error below :

```
[dcc32 Error] : E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'shortdateformat'
```

How to do the same thing on the new Delphi ?

Thanks

Comment: Useful tip. Paste the error message text into the search field of your preferred websearch.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for the minus point on my question, as usual :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just learned that i need to use these commands instead :

```
FormatSettings.shortdateformat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
FormatSettings.dateseparator := '/';
```

Comment: Rather than using the global `FormatSettings` variable, it is usually preferable to instead pass a local `TFormatSettings` variable to whatever formatting function you are using, eg: `var fmt: TFormatSettings; fmt := TFormatSettings.Create; fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy'; fmt.DateSeparator := '/'; <FunctionName>(..., fmt);` The global variables are not thread-safe, which is why `TFormatSettings` was even introduced in the first place.